# `TypeError: invalid type promotion` when concatenating two numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I think I'm still not that familiar with NumPy. I have the issue that I want to create something like a Matrix. To do so I create my time vector by using `np.datetime64` which works just fine. I get an array with the shape `(300001,), dtype('<M8[us]')`. So I would like to concatenate it with my other matrix that has a shape of `(300001, 12), dtype('float64')`. I guess the main issue is the dtype because if I try to concatenate I get the error in the title. To concatenate I use the following:

```
com_interpolated_matrix = np.concatenate((time_vector, interpolated_matrix), axis=1)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Arrays are homogeneous. They cannot contain two different datatypes. It sounds like Pandas would be more what you are looking for?

Comment: What `dtype` and `shape` did you hope to produce?

Comment: i hope to get the shape (300001, 13). The dtype is not important as long as it works

Comment: @alkasm actually that solved my problem. I switched to pandas thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You can use numpy.column_stack:

np.column_stack((array1,array2))

Comment: How is that going to help with this error?  `column_stack` will correct his shape mismatch, but doesn't deal with the `dtype` error.